# Report viewer is always showing loading but never loads data, after button click in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, rdlc, reportviewer

I have an error while loading data to the aspx page ReportViewer. There is no error showing in the application while debugging, but the report viewer in the aspx page keeps loading infinitely once the button click event is finished.

//ASPX page goes like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Views.DashBoard.Test" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<h1>RDLC</h1>

<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Generate Report" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"/>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"  Width="100%"> </rsweb:ReportViewer>

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

// CS page goes like this

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataSet1 dt = GetData();  //in data set i am getting data by calling the function GetData()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt.Tables[0]));
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Report1.rdlc");
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Can you press F12 and then run the report and see if the ReportViewerControl is hanging up on a javascript error? Those errors will show up as red squgglies under the console tab.

Comment: Yes Ross there seems to have an error in the console tab and it goes like this.

MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PRM_UnknownToken' of undefined
    at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._parseDelta (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6)
    at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmitCompleted (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6)
    at Array.<anonymous> (MicrosoftAjax.js:6)
    at MicrosoftAjax.js:6
    at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (MicrosoftAjax.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onReadyStateChange (MicrosoftAjax.js:6)

Comment: Yes Ross in another application in which report viewer is working fine without any error is not throwing the error in the console tab. So I guess this error is the reason for my report viewer to go for loading infinitely.

Comment: **Report viewer which is not working has the following configuration.**
Dot net framework version - 4.5
Report viewer version no - 11.00.

**Report viewer which is working has the following configuration.**
Dot net framework version - 4.6.1
Report viewer version no - 15.00.